# Distribute colored balls in distinct boxes in known quantities

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ balls, each in one of $C$ different colors. The amount of balls in each color $k$ is given by $n_k$, such that:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{C}{n_k} = n$

I want to distribute $m$ of these in $B$ numbered boxes in known quantities - box $k$ gets $b_k$ balls. So:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^B{b_k} = m, m\le n$

Considering that balls with the same color are indistinguishable, how many distinct results can I get? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: You cannot solve this unless you tell us (or give a variable name) to the number of balls distributed, which your second equation allows to be less than $n$.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer it is a variable number. I'd like a general solution, but just solving the $n = m$ case would go a long way